# Alarms not cancelled

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

I'm using the following code to cancel all my alarms and reset them:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < mArrayList.size(); i++) {
  Intent receiverIntent = new Intent(mContext, AlarmReceiver.class);
        int _id = (int) mArrayList.get(i).getDateMillis(); //(int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, _id, receiverIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(mContext.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(sender);
        setAlarm(mContext, receiverIntent, mArrayList.get(i).getType(), _id, sender, alarmManager);
           }

    public static void setAlarm(Context context, Intent receiverIntent, String typ, long timeMillis, PendingIntent pendingIntent, AlarmManager 
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(timeMillis);
        long sdl = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

        String notificationTitle = "My Title";
        String notificationText = "My Text";
        receiverIntent.putExtra("notificationTitle", notificationTitle);
        receiverIntent.putExtra("notificationText", notificationText);
        receiverIntent.putExtra("notificationDateTime", sdl);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, sdl, pendingIntent);
    }
```

Problem is that when I first call `CancelAllAlarms()` and then set my alarms the new alarms are created very good but the old ones are not deleted.
And so if I do a `adb shell dumpsys alarm > D:\test.txt` the first time I have about 200 entries, the next the the app is run I have about 400, then 600 etc...

**EDIT**

I changed my code a lot because I'm now storing my generated ID's inside a DB which works fine. So my code has changed quiet significant:

Intent receiverIntent = new Intent(mContext, AlarmReceiver.class);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(mContext.ALARM_SERVICE);

```
    String[] alarms = getAllAlarmsFromDB(databaseHAlarms, databaseHAlarms.tableName_alarms);
    for (int i = 0; i < alarms.length; i++) {
        //alarms[i] now holds the ID set before (see codee below)
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, Integer.parseInt(alarms[i]), receiverIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.cancel(sender);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < mArrayList.size(); i++) {
        long timeMillis = mArrayList.get(i).getDateMillis();
        int _id = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mArrayList.get(i).getDateMillis()).substring(0, 8));
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, _id, receiverIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        insertAlarmIntoMySQL(databaseHAlarms, getMD5(timeMillis + ""), String.valueOf(mArrayList.get(i).getDateMillis()).substring(0, 8));

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, sdl, sender);
    }
```

Comment: In addition to the answer from user8, the best way would be to make the alarmManager and the 'PendingIntent' global and use them for start and cancel. And if you develop target >=Marshmallow, be sure that you have read this: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html

Comment: what is your goal to set _id as System.timeInMillis()?...that´s very unusual....

Comment: Very interesting read about Doze, thanks for that! I'm using the system millis because I saw that in a lot of articles / example codes for alarms. What would you recommend using instead?

Comment: which tutorials made this? This gonna lead you into the wrong direction, I guess or these tuts had some other goal. A simple step to set an unique `Id` is for example the `count` from your `arrayList item`. You just have to adjust your method `setAlarm` to `setAlarm(Context context, Intent receiverIntent, String type, long timeMillis, int id)`  and pass it in your loop with `setAlarm(mContext, receiverIntent, mArrayList.get(i).getType(), mArrayList.get(i).getDateMillis(),i);`

Comment: And one better way to set alarms is, not to set them all at the same time, instead, set next alarm after the one that is passed.

Comment: The problem is that I need to reset all the alarms because on every refresh the data changes and the alarms need to be correct again. But like I wrote below the problem is that this error also happens when using a static id for all my operations.

Comment: can you please update your code? We need to see the current one to get the problem...

Comment: Done! The only thing I've changed was switching from systemMillis to int 1234...

Comment: this might be, that you have not used a global AlarmManager and PendingIntent. You are creating everytime a new alarmManager and PendingIntent you call this method. You need to make them as one Object that is only initialized if it is null. But then, You need to give unique ID´s if you want to have multiple alarms. It´s like I said, better to start the next alarm if alarm was passed.

Comment: I find this discussion all very hard to believe. With the current code, OP is using exactly the same parameters to create the `PendingIntent` (same ID, same `Intent`). This means that there will only ever be one active `PendingIntent` for all alarms. All the other `PendingIntent`s have been canceled (since OP used `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`. Please update the post with your current code and make sure you uninstall your app (which will delete any random `PendingIntent` and/or scheduled alarms) and reinstall before running it again and reporting the situation.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs You do not need to use a global `AlarmManager`. You can get one every time you want to use it. There is only ever one `AlarmManager` available within a process. When you call `getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE)`, Android returns a reference to the `AlarmManager` within the current process. If you call it 1000 times, you will always get a reference to the same `AlarmManager`.

Comment: @David yes you are correct, but this was only an assumption because it didn´t work. The questioner has updated the code, above is the current one. So my thought was to try it like this way and see if it fixes the problem. And yes, since you mentioned it, it could be a problem fixed by uninstall. I did not think about that, sometimes you forget the simplest things. Sorry for misleading here...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs thanks for your comments! I'm using the exact code right now and I have also uninstalled the app completely. I even set up a new AVD to test it -> same results... I really don't know what else I could try...

Comment: OK......let´s reset...is your current problem still the problem described in your question or is anything working now after changing the code?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs yes still the same problem with the code above. Do I need any special permissions that I've missed?

Comment: I´m a little bit confused about your code in the question because you are starting the alarm directly after cancel...is this just a paste issue here?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I have changed the code a lot (Added mysqlite database etc.), could you check the code again?

Comment: ok, Change your PendingIntent to `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` (on both set and cancel() method)and be sure the same context is used. Also be sure the id is correct, because It seems a little bit confusing to me as I don´t know the code. If you are sure everything is set correctly, it should work.

Comment: With UPDATE instead of CANCEL it works great! Thanks a lot! I will update everything once I'm finished fixing everything!

Comment: great, so I put an answer.... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to user13s answer, you have to use `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` on the `PendingIntent`.

So in summary, be sure to use same `Context`and `id` and use `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`:

**start the alarm:**

```
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, id, receiverIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, sender);
```

**stop the alarm:**

```
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, id, receiverIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CUPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmManager.cancel(sender);
```

### Why

Well, it´s not exactly clear/documented why `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` is not working, but I have read this often here in SO. The docs tell us, that this cancels an existing `PendingIntent` and creates a new one and you can use this if you want to change some `extra data` inside the `intent`.

`FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` is described like:

*This can be used if you are creating intents where only the extras change, and don't care that any entities that received your previous PendingIntent will be able to launch it with your new extras even if they are not explicitly given to it.*

From these two description I can´t see a reason why it shouldn´t work with `alarmManager.cancel()` if you use `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` . Maybe it´s because that the `PendingIntent`is canceled and recreated through the `FLAG` before `alarmManager.cancel()` is able to.

### Marshmallow

For marshmallow there are some new circumstances. Cancel should work like before, there is no change. But setting an alarm with `alarmManager.set()`will not work if device falls into doze mode. The docs describing that you have to use `setAndAllowWhileIdle()`, `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` or `setAlarmClock()`.

**BUT ONLY DO THIS IF YOUR APP NEEDS TO FIRE ALARMS ON DOZE!** So to prepare your app for Marshmallow, you should check the API versions and set the method it depends on.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {   

  PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, id, receiverIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
   alarmManager.setAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, sender);


} else {        

    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, id, receiverIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, sender);
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer and especially for the marshmallow addition! I'm adding extras to my Intent when setting the alarm and it seems to work anyway. Is it possible that the extras are ignored when the Intents are compared?

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass exactly the same `PendingIntent` to `alarmManager.cancel()` that you passed to `alarmManager.set()`.

In your code `_id` will differ, thus the `PendingIntent`s won't be equal, so cancel will not work.

The IDs should be unique (except if you always want to cancel all of them), but when you want to cancel a particular alarm, you need to know the ID you used for the `PendingIntent` when created it, and use that exact same ID to cancel it.

I recommend storing the IDs in SQLite database.